# How to get the while loop running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, list, while-loop

For your better understanding:
i try to make an intersection control for cars with a list (intersectionList) in which every car writes his address if the car wants to cross the intersection.

If the cars over the road piece 20 oder 23 they write their address in the list and if their entry has the index 0, they are allowed to pass. As soon as they crossed the intersection (piece10) they remove their entry from the list. My problem is now with the while loop. The cars do everything i want, but don´t adapt their speed after their list index was changed from >=1 to == 0. Which means in real life, that they recognize that their index was not 0, stopp, but than they stop for ever... so i think there is a problem with the while loop.

```
class Logic:

    intersectionList = []

    def logic(self, addr, piece):
        if piece == 20:
            self.intersectionList.append(addr)

            while self.intersectionList.index(addr) >= 1: #as long index of list is not 0
                self.car.changeSpeed(0, 1000)  #stop car
            else:
                self.car.changeSpeed(300, 1000) #start car

        elif piece == 23: 
            self.intersectionList.append(addr)

            while self.intersectionList.index(addr) >= 1:
                self.car.changeSpeed(0, 1000) #stop car
            else:
                self.car.changeSpeed(300, 1000) #start car

        elif piece == 10:
           if addr in self.intersectionList:
               self.intersectionList.remove(addr)
```

---

Here we go. The Overdrive class is a python wrapper for the official ANKI Overdrive SDK and too long to upload it here. 
github link: https://github.com/xerodotc/overdrive-python.git

```
from overdrive import Overdrive


class Logic:


    intersectionList = []

    def  __init__(self, macAddress):
        car = Overdrive(macAddress)



    def locationChangeCallback(self, addr, location, piece, speed, clockwise):
        self.logic(addr, piece)

    def logic(self, addr, piece):

        if piece == 20:
            self.intersectionList.append(addr)

            while self.intersectionList.index(addr) >= 1:  # as long index of list is not 0
                self.car.changeSpeed(0, 1000)  # stop car

            else:
                self.car.changeSpeed(300, 1000)  # start car


        elif piece == 23:
            self.intersectionList.append(addr)

            while self.intersectionList.index(addr) >= 1:
                self.car.changeSpeed(0, 1000)  # stop car

            else:
                self.car.changeSpeed(300, 1000)  # start car

        elif piece == 10:
            if addr in self.intersectionList:
             self.intersectionList.remove(addr)





    def startEngine(self):
        self.car.setLocationChangeCallback(self.locationChangeCallback)
        self.car.changeSpeed(300,1000)


# instances

bmw = Logic("CD:DF:4R:53:34:D3")
bmw.startEngine()

lambo = Logic("CD:DF:4R:53:34:D3")
lambo.startEngine()
```

Comment: I don't  know whether that's the reason, but `intersection_list` is a _class_ (like, static) variable, which is unlikely what you want.

Comment: Hi, is this the whole class Logic ? If so where is the variable car initialized  or passed?

Comment: No i want it like that. Every car has a logic object and i want, just one list for all objects.. I m new to python but i looked up in the internet and they said, that its done like this. Even when i print out the list, everything looks fine

Comment: no it´s not. You guys need it?

Comment: okk okk another question I have is what are the two parameters of changeSpeed?

Comment: first one is the speed (0-1000), second the acceleration (0-1000)

Comment: could it be because of the elif in elif piece == 10:? you wait in 20 and 23 but when you leave these waits you don't pass the last elif.

Comment: lambo = Logic("CD:DF:4R:53:34:D3")
bmw.startEngine() this must be lambo

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: How do you expect to ever leave a while loop? You don't modify the intersection list in the loop - meaning its indices and therfore the while conditions are constant. How do you know the while loop is never entered? Are you aware that this code is not multithreaded?

Comment: Okay, maybey that’s the problem.. how do I make the function multithreaded?

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace

```
while self.interSectionList.index(addr) >= 1:
```

with

```
while self.interSectionList.index(addr) >= 0:
```

Comment: No i don´t think so. I want that the speed of the car stays =0 as long as their listIndex is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of mind boggling:

```
        self.intersectionList.append(addr)

        while self.intersectionList.index(addr) >= 1: #as long index of list is not 0
            self.car.changeSpeed(0, 1000)  #stop car
```

The index won't change unless it is done in changeSpeed. So to answer your question some insight in changeSpeed would be handy.

Comment: I don't understand.. Lets give the following example: Two cars are on the track and every of these two cars want to cross the ontersection. So both of them put the address in the list and the first one which put in its address there is allowed to drive because index ==0. As soon as it passes track 10, the list entry gets removed and the entry of the other car moves to index 0. Now this car is allowed to cross the intersection

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. Is it possible that you upload a working piece of code so readers can understand how your function works in its context?